# JavaScript. Как получить значение ключа, название которого указано в двойных квадратных скобках?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, это функция под названием `s` (в виде ключей), функцию `s` заключил в массив `[s]`, чтобы показать ключи.

Нужно программно получить значение ключа *`[[BoundThis]]`* переменной `s`.

Comment: Похоже, что для сей задачи всё печально - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41666584/10179415

Comment: Кстати, чтобы посмотреть такие свойства в консоли, не заключая функцию в массив, можно использовать `console.dir(func)`.

Answer (score 1):

Этого нельзя сделать. Значения указанные в двойных скобках, это внутренние свойства(Internal Slots).

- [Object Internal Properties and Methods | es5.github.io](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2)
- [Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots | ecma-international](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)